# Macro to insert a blank row in Excel if cell above and cell below have the same content

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet where in column A are text values like:

- Italy
- Italy
- England
- England
- England
- Greece
- Germany
- Germany
- Germany
- Germany

I need to add a blank row between each countries group to separate them and have a better view

I already tried to match them but what I get is just TRUE/FALSE but don't know how to get the reference and where to add the blank row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub StackTest()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For c = LastRow To 5 Step -1
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c).Value <> ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c - 1) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: That is so great @Permanoob. I have headers at first 3 rows, is it possible to start checking after A3 and going down?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than insert a blank row, better to change the height of the row so that you preserve the ability to sort and filter.
Use this: `Rows(c).RowHeight = 24.75` (you can change the number to your liking) in place of `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c).EntireRow.Insert`